# Keep dial pad open during call. Proximity sensor NOT activated

Tags: calls, screen-timeout

I often keep my phone on speaker and muted away from my face. The screen goes completely blank after 10 seconds. This makes it very difficult to unmute and unspeaker myself if I need to say something. When I'm not in a call my screen goes dark after 2mins which is fine. I want my screen to remain on until the screen timeout or proximity sensor is activated.

Comment: Have you tried any automation app for this? Tasker, MacroDroid, Automate -- these apps can be given a try. A simplistic trigger and an action would likely be: if on call save user's screen timeout, set screen timeout to X minutes. When call ends -> reset screen timeout to user's screen timeout.

Comment: I will try those apps @Firelord

Comment: @Firelord they don't work